# How to configure remote server for "SSH access without a password"?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-server

How to configure remote server for "SSH-access without a password" if I have root-passwords of remote servers?

And can I configure this only for non-password SSH-access from my machine, not from others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try performing a Google search?

Read: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

Answer (score 0):

sorry for answering i can't comment :/, using ssh without password is possible using trusted keys between two hosts, easy tutorial here:

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html